# Putting the name of new created folder in the path of csv file

Tags: python-3.x, file, mkdir

I am trying to create new csv file in the new created folder, i am asking how can i put the name of new created folder in the path of the csv file

```
   import os  
   def creat(i,ii):   
   # Directory  
   directory = "NEW"+str(i) 
   # Parent Directory path  
   parent_dir = 'C:\\Users\\lap\\Desktop\\parfolder\\'
   path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory )   
   os.mkdir(path)  
   print("Directory '% s' created" % directory)  
   with open('C:\\Users\\lap\\Desktop\\parfolder\\%s\\MM%s.csv' %directory 
             %ii , 'w') as file:
        for i in range(1,10):
            file.write("{}\n".format(i))
for i in range(1,4):
   creat(i,i)
```

Comment: It looks like your code does that. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: yes i have this error FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\lap\\Desktop\\parfolder\\new1'

Comment: Ok, I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your error you can wrap the `os.mkdir(path)` call in a try, except construct:

```
try:
    os.mkdir(path)
except FileExistsError:
    pass
```

Edit:
Now you changed the code so you'll have to change this, too:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\lap\\Desktop\\parfolder\\%s\\MM%s.csv' % (directory,  
          i), 'w') as file:
```

Comment: Can you see my update code please , now i have this error typeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: @oleva: do you mean to use `i` and not `ii`? Because `ii` is not defined in your code.

Comment: I used ii in side function , you are the best :) thank you